# What is the difference between BillingClient.queryPurchases vs IInAppBillingService.getPurchases (for account hold and restore implementation)

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing, google-play-billing

I'm trying to implement the account hold and restore stuff that Google Play is starting to require by Nov 1, 2020. In the documentation it states

> "If your app relies solely on queryPurchases() to determine whether a user is entitled to a subscription, then your app should automatically handle the subscription recovering from account hold."
> https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs#account-hold

Right now I'm using `IInAppBillingService.getPurchases` instead of `BillingClient.queryPurchases`. What I'm wondering is, will `getPurchases` automatically handle the subscription recovering from account hold like `queryPurchases` does or not?